# Should I make different sites or different pages for SharePoint classes?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2010

I am working on creating a SharePoint for one of the programs at my University.

I am going to use the site to separate different classes (ex: Class level 300, Class level 400, Class level 500, etc...) and the each class will have an area to view uploaded documents and things like that.

Would be it best to make different sites on the SharePoint and have different permissions on those sites? Or would it be better to just have one site and different pages with for the classes.

I tried doing it with just one site and different pages, but the permission levels didn't work for me.

Please ask any more detailed questions if I am being too vague.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to create a main site collection and create subsites for each class. The subsites will be independent of each other in terms of permissions and you can manage them more easily.

Pages are more difficult to manage because then you have to be sneaky with restricting users from viewing all site content etc.